# Difference between Task of subtype 'Email' and EmailMessage

Tags: tasks, emailmessage

How can the difference between the following queries be explained:

1. the output from the object Task where TaskSubtype = 'Email'
2. the output from the object EmailMessage

I've noticed that 1 > 2.

Comment: `1 > 2` meaning the count of Tasks where TaskSubType = `Email` > count of `EmailMessage` ?  Count might differ depending on when Enhanced Email feature was enabled; also automation can set Tasks.TaskSubType upon creation without necessarily sending an Email